# Cancel rate keeps returning 100%, not sure if I'm misunderstanding CTEs

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to calculate cancel rate for transactions with close dates in 2022. However, I keep running into an issue where cancel rate keeps returning 100% and I'm wondering if it may be because of my misunderstanding of how to use CTEs.

Data lives in two tables: `ad` and `transactions`. Ad is set up in such a way that if a transaction had a close date and that close date later changes, both are recorded.

As an example, if transaction 10 was supposed to close on 9/15/22 but closed on 9/22/22 instead, there is entry for (ordeid: 10 | closedate: 9/15/22) & for (orderid: 10 | closedate: 9/22/22). I'm only interested in the earliest possible close date, hence the `MIN(a.closedate)`.

```sql
WITH cancelled AS (
   SELECT a.orderid AS "Order",
          MIN(a.closedate) AS "CloseDate"
   FROM ad.order_history a
   WHERE a.closedate < current_date
     AND a.status = 'Cancelled'
     AND a.closedate IS NOT NULL
     AND a.orderid IS NOT NULL
     AND a.closedate >= '2022-01-01'
   GROUP by 1
   ORDER BY 2
)

SELECT DATE_TRUNC('month', c.closedate) AS "Month",
       COUNT(DISTINCT t.ad_id) AS "Total Orders", 
       COUNT(DISTINCT c.order) / COUNT(DISTINCT t.id) AS "Cancel Rate"

FROM transactions t
LEFT JOIN cancelled c ON t.ad_id = c.order
WHERE (t.ad_id IS NOT null OR t.order_number IS NOT NULL)
  AND DATE_TRUNC('year', c.closedate) >= '2022-01-01'
  AND c.closedate < current_date
  AND t.deleted_at IS NULL 
GROUP BY 1
```

When I run this query, the 'Cancelled rate' returns as 100%, which makes me a little confused. Logically, counting only `distinct t.a_id`, `a.orderid`, and `t.id` should return the same number. I thought making the CTE results in picking certain ids from `a.orderid`, so `c.order` should not be equal to `a.orderid`, as it's all the transactions that have been canceled, not all the transactions generally.

I must have misunderstood/misused CTE then, since it keeps returning 100%, which tells me it's picking out all of the `a.orderid` values, not just the canceled ones. I'm not quite sure how to fix it/get it to work correctly and would appreciate any pointers. Thank you!

Comment: `AND c.closedate < current_date` any time you apply an operator like this to a field value on the right side of your left join, you effectively make it into an inner join (all the nulls become `false` and are filtered right out.

Comment: I tried removing this condition, but it still gives me the same result

Comment: And to add, you have two `WHERE` conditions that redundantly repeat conditions in CTE.

Comment: @elissa Remove the `DATE_TRUNC('year', c.closedate) >= '2022-01-01'` too

Comment: Very interesting you use mixed type quoted alias in CTE with `"Order"` but refer to column in all lower casing `order` in outer query with no error of unknown columns. Same with `"CloseDate"` and `closedate`.

Comment: @elissa Remember the order of operations of a SQL query: the `FROM`, and therefore the `LEFT JOIN`, is executed first. The `WHERE` then filters rows out of the table created in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: @JohnK. I tried removing DATE_TRUNC('year', c.closedate) >= '2022-01-01' & also removing the c.closedate<current_date (separately and together) but for some reason it still shows the same result as it did before

Comment: @topsail. Huh? `select null < now(); NULL`. [Functions comparison](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html): *Ordinary comparison operators yield null (signifying “unknown”), not true or false, when either input is null.*

Comment: No problem. I just mean it has the same effect as false - filtered out. Just like false. Apologies for the misleading terminology.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but a long form comment with the idea of getting at answer. Observations:

1. You are not working on table `ad`, you are using table `order_history` in schema `ad`.
2. As mentioned in the comments I don't see `a.orderid AS "Order"` and `ON t.ad_id = c.order` working. Same for  `MIN(a.closedate) AS "CloseDate"` and `c.closedate`. The double quotes would force the identifier to uppercase and that would not work with the lowercase usage later on. This leads me to believe the query you posted is not the query you are running. To your question add the actual query you are running.
3. You describe the purpose of `order_history` but you have not described the purpose of `transactions` and more importantly what their relationship is? Also add the schema definitions for both tables.
4. You can simplify this:
   `a.closedate < current_date ...  AND a.closedate >= '2022-01-01'`
   to:
   `WHERE a.closedate BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND (current_date - '1 day'::interval)`
5. Why `t.ad_id IS NOT null`?